# Transform which produces default namespace convention xmlns="..."

Tags: xslt-1.0

Given the following xml:

```
<root xmlns="example.com">
  <child />
</root>
```

What xslt (version 1.0) can be used to produce:

```
<newRoot xmlns="stackoverflow.com">
  <child />
</newroot>
```

I've tried various combinations of exclude-result-prefixes and namespace-alias. E.g,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:e="example.com" xmlns:s="stackoverflow.com" exclude-result-prefixes="e">

<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="s" result-prefix="#default" />

    <xsl:template match="e:root">
        <s:newRoot>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </s:newRoot>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e:child">
        <s:child />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The closest I've come is the following incorrect xml

```
<newRoot>
  <child />
</newroot>
```

EDIT: I apologize for the overly simple sample.
The solution I'm searching for will change the default namespace AND make transformations to my xml. Here is a more sophisticated example of what I would like to do:

```
<Data xmlns="sample.com/public">
  <Insured>
    <Name>Sample Client</Name>
    <Locations>
      <Location Number="1">
        <Address>
          <City>New York</City>
          <State>New York</State>
          <Street>222 10 Street</Street>
        </Address>
      </Location>
      <Location Number="2">
        <Address>
          <City>New York</City>
          <State>New York</State>
          <Street>3538 27 Street</Street>
        </Address>
      </Location>
    </Locations>
    <Coverages>
      <LocationSplit>
        <LocationNumber>1</LocationNumber>
        <Clause>
          <Limit>10000000</Limit>
        </Clause>
      </LocationSplit>
    </Coverages>
  </Insured>
</Data>
```

Which would become

```
<projection xmlns="sample.com/projected">
  <insured>
    <name>Sample Client</name>
    <location address="222 10 Street New York, New York">
      <clause>
        <limit>10000000</limit>
      </clause>
    </location>
  </insured>
</projection>
```

I thought exclude-result-prefix and namespace-alias were the ticket because I could explicitly use each namespace by declaring them in my stylesheet and then remove the /public namespace while aliasing the /projection namespace to the #default. However, the alias causes the namespace to simply be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand what in your question is real and what is just an example. To take your example literally (as your own answer does), the answer would be:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="stackoverflow.com"
xmlns:e="example.com" 
exclude-result-prefixes="e">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/e:root">
    <newRoot>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </newRoot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e:child">
    <child/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A more generic answer, that would move **all** elements from their existing namespace/s to the new namespace would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="stackoverflow.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Placing the xmlns="stackoverflow.com" in the stylesheet root node and declaring new nodes without a prefix is the way to achieve what I wanted. Thanks! I would still love an explanation about why using xsl:namespace-alias to move a prefix into the default namespace causes the namespace url to not be printed at all.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to use `xsl:namespace-alias` here at all; in any case, if you're using it with `result-prefix="#default"` then you must also define a default namespace. Otherwise the "real" namespace is no-namespace and this *will* be printed as `xmlns:s=""`.

Comment: There's the crux of my misunderstanding. I thought the namespace-alias was changing the prefix but not the namespace. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you merely want to literally match the input root and literally output your result document, just do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:ex="example.com"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                exclude-result-prefixes="ex">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/ex:root">
    <newRoot xmlns="stackoverflow.com">
      <child/>
    </newRoot>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That works but may or may not meet your general needs.  Below is another transformation that you or others might find more useful...

## XSLT to Change All Element Namespaces

The following XSLT will change the namespace of all elements to `stackoverflow.com`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|processing-instruction()|comment()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="stackoverflow.com">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```